# Can you use arduino for other avr chips?

Tags: arduino, avr

Example:
Arduino ***leonardo*** uses **Atmega32U4**. What if one wants to program/develop for the plain **ATmega32**.

Comment: "Arduino" is an agglomeration of lot of separate projects: A **terrible** Text editor, a java code-munging tool so you don't have to write proper C++, AVR-GCC for the actual compiling, AVRDude for programming, the optiboot bootloader, etc... Which part, specifically, do you want to use?

Comment: @ConnorWolf  I agree that the editor is quite **terrible**, well I'm most interested in using the _library_ part. Quite often I need to do Proof_Of_concept stuff and using those libraries makes my life easy.

Comment: I refuse to call it a IDE. In any event, have you tried [Stino](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino)? It's the toolchain and libraries, coupled to probably the best text editor ever, sublime text. I use the toolchain for quick&lazy prototyping myself a lot as well (through stino), though I tend to basically only use the serial libraries, and do the rest myself (IO pins, interrupts, etc...).

Comment: @ConnorWolf At present, I use notepad++ with avr-gcc/WinAVR for my AVR projects. Most of my code is hand-crafted. *Stino* seems a good option.. But Sublime is too *costly*. I'll have to stick to *arduino* till I find some workaround like *Stino* for notepad++.

Comment: It only took a few seconds to google the answer to your question.  if there is a supported arduino board that uses that part, then why wouldnt you be able to use it with the arduino libraries and tools?  get the arduino bootloader on the part wire it right, and there you go.

Comment: @dwelch It seems my question confused you. I don't want to program a specific chip(as in above example chip atmega32)  rather I am looking for a general approach for any chip. How will I do it for atmega8U2/4, atmega 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Arduino IDE with any MCU you can find [compatibility files](https://github.com/eaconner/ATmega32-Arduino) for. You may need to use a ISP programmer though, unless you can also find an appropriate bootloader (which you'll need a ISP programmer to upload regardless).

Comment: Is there some literature/tut/blog on **How to create such  compatibility files** (apart from reverse engineering them) ?

Comment: I haven't found any yet, the best thing is probably to [start here](http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/ArduinoOnOtherAtmelChips) and muck around.

Comment: Thanks, That's very helpful. I was looking (exactly)for this. See [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=211376), I never reached it( the link provided by you).